# Access data from smartsheet in php

Tags: php

I am getting problem to fetch data from smartsheet. this code return ***`bool(false)`***.
What is the problem?

```
<?php
    $baseURL = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0";
    $getSheetURL = $baseURL. "/sheets/139303239083xxx/rows?include=objectValue";
    $accessToken = "5b2hlajx8rs26ttiy677hhoxxx"; 

    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". $accessToken ,  "Content-Type: application/json");


    $ch = curl_init($getSheetURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $getSheetResponseData = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($getSheetResponseData);

    $sheetObj = json_decode($getSheetResponseData);

    echo "<h1>Sheet name: ". $sheetObj->name ."</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: Check the curl documentation on [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). It will probably contain the answer you seek.

Comment: when i add url in browser it shows:                                                                                {"errorCode" : 1006,
  "message" : "Not Found",
  "refId" : "1hes9h2k3jgum"}       https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheet/139303239083XXX

Comment: where we add this cacert.poem file after downloading???      https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Comment: Again check the [curl documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Take a look at the CURLOPT_CAINFO as well as CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST settings in particular.

Comment: Thanks. @kurt it's working now.